# Как верстать такие и подобные этому графики?

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как верстаются подобные графики? При том что это скорее всего не просто фоновая картинка, потому что точки по ховеру/клику вызывают всплывающие окна.(Скорее всего. Макет из интернета, взят ради практики)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть построен с svg или сзади стоит видео с слайдером. Если для интереса можете дать ссылку?

Comment: https://www.figma.com/file/8T4byFDAV5REmnVyQlsFO1/clean_and_simple_website_freebie_work_file?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: Привет! если не нашли ответ на этот вопрос этот приложение вам поможет по моему )
https://www.shapedivider.app/